# Is there any Java Framework to manipulate/draw a Cartesian plane?

Tags: java, frameworks, java-2d, cartesian

I would like to know if there is any Java Framework or resource to draw and/or manipulate a Cartesian Plane. Obviously, it can be done using just Java 2d, but implement some resources like "zoom in" and "zoom out" are not so trivial to develop

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Java 2D contains the `AffineTransform` class, which makes it easy to use a matrix to specify a transformation on the Cartesian Plane.  It's also easy to apply this transform to your `Graphics2D` object through its `setTransform` method.

You can use a standard transform to apply your own coordinate system onto screen coordinates.  Then you can manipulate this transform to account for panning and zooming.  This will allow you to use your own coordinate system for laying out your content while completely abstracting away all of the panning and zooming functionality into one place.